# jQuery match from value string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to match a variable from an url. This works fine if I use the expression directly in the match method. However I am having problem getting it to work if the expression is inside a string.

> var match = '/(page_art_list=\d+)/';

match contains the value..

```
var pattern = "/("+paramName+"=\d+)/";
var match = this.href.match(pattern);
```

match is null

I have double checked that both examples produce exactly the same string.

Any thoughts?

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/something/` syntax is for regexp literals. For strings, use the `RegExp` constructor:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('(' + paramName + '=\\d+)');
```

Note the double backslash `\\`. This is because within strings, `\` is an escape character, so you need two to represent a single, regexp backslash.